# Postgres query can't select specific geolocation

Tags: php, sql, json, api, postgresql

I'm writing some API and I have a stupid problem. If i run a query

```
SELECT * FROM u.loc
```

it will list every user location with some data and param `"geocode"`

```
ex. "geocode":"(48.2078099,16.3667456)"
```

(this is in json format only on output not in database)

But if i run a query

```
SELECT * FROM u.loc WHERE geocode = '(48.2078099,16.3667456)'
```

It will return empty result. 
I don't have idea what is the problem here, if somebody know please answer. Thanks

p.s. I'm using PostgreSQL and php, and I don't have direct access to database(pgadmin)

Comment: Try selecting everything that likes inside a box surrounding that point. I'm guessing it's a floating-point accuracty issue.

Comment: What is the data type of "geocode"?

Comment: Problem was solved 5 hrs ago with query SELECT * FROM u.loc WHERE geocode[0] = ? AND geocode[1] = ? .Thanks for trying to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the exact value `"geocode":"(48.2078099,16.3667456)"`.  JSON is not the best format to save in the database.

```
SELECT * FROM u.loc WHERE geocode = '"geocode":"(48.2078099,16.3667456)"'
```

Comment: My mistake in question, it's not in json format in database i'm using json just for output. This also not working.